# Function needed to fit data

Tags: functions

I ran some computations and there seems to be some neat relationship between my variable $t$ and the corresponding result. What function should I try first to fit my data?

It is given that:

- $t$ is a non-negative integer (0, 1, 2, ..)
- $0 \le f(t) \le 1$, for any $t$
- $f(0) = 1$

It would be nice if the function would have two parameters:

- First one - let's call it $a$ - should control how steeply the function falls in the beginning. In extreme cases the function may stay flat at value 1, or it could fall to 0 immediately (at $t=1$).
- Another parameter $b$ should control what value function approaches asymptotically as $t$ grows to infinity.

[image]

**Update**

Based on Mr. Leibovici's advise and my own toying around, I excluded the exponent. It just doesn't fit the data.

For now I came up with the following function.

$f(t)=(1-b)(a_1 t+1)^{-a_2}+b$

It fits the data very well, but it's quite ugly. And it has three parameters instead of two ($a_1$ and $a_2$ together do, what my original $a$ parameter was supposed to do). Are there any mathematical trickery which could improve on these shortcomings?

For now I'll try to gather some more data. Maybe fitting the parameters will suggest some relationship.

Comment: Could you provide some data points (say between $0$ and $200$) ? You have my e-mail address in my profile. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like 
$$f(t) = b+Ae^{-at}$$ where from your graph it looks like $b\simeq0.35$. $A$ could be found from the condition that $f(0)=1$, so here $A=1-b$.

One way to check, once you have found $b$ would be to plot $\ln (f-b)$ against $t$ which should be a straight line...

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

What danimal answered is almost what I was typing when the phone rang !

You want to fit $$f(t)=b+A e^{-at}$$ and, since $f(0)=1$, the model becomes $$f(t)=b+(1-b)e^{-at}$$ and you have an idea of the value of $b$ (given by the asymptote). So, in a preliminary step, define $$g(t)=-\log\Big(\frac{f(t)-b}{1-b}\Big)=a t$$ So, using all data points $$a=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n t_i g_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n t_i^2}$$ But, these values are only estimates (you measure $f$ but not any of its possible transforms) butt you now have in hands everything required for a rigorous nonlinear fit minimizing $$SSQ(a,b)=\sum_{i=1}^n \Big(f_i-\big(b+(1-b)e^{-at_i}\big)\Big)^2$$ and, because of good and consistent estimates, it will converge in very few iterations.

**Edit**

You could even skip the first part and go directly to the nonlinear regression using the slope at the origin since $f'(0)=-a(1-b)$, so $a$.

Comment: Why are you using an exponential fit instead of, say, $f(t) = \frac{bt+1}{(t+1)^a}$?

Comment: Yes, indeed but why not ? The problem with the function you propose is the horizontal asymptote, I guess. Do you agree ?

Comment: Of course, you are right: I forgot an exponent! :) What about $f(t) = \frac{bt^a + 1}{(t+1)^a}$?

Comment: @A.P. I totally agree with you. There could be many functions to fit this kind of data $f(t) = \frac{bt^a + 1}{(t+c)^a}$ could be another one, just derived from your. Cheers :-)

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is not "Hey, this could be a fit, too!", but "Why did you propose an exponential fit?". For example: is it because it is the easiest to check, or maybe because it provides a very good fit in most (practical) cases, even if it is not exact?

Comment: I would say first that because it is very easy to check if data follow an exponential form (just a scatter plot of the data after some simple transforms). For most problems in physics, exponential laws are very common. And my last and worst reason is my age and the number of times I faced this kind of data. But again, you may be totally right and who knows if the function you propose is not better. If I had the data points, I should try. But, being almost blind, it is difficult for me to pick the numbers from the plot. I shall ask the OP.

Comment: @A.P. One problem with the function you propose : the derivative cancels for $t=b^{\frac{1}{1-a}}$